# Connecting a HDMI device that isn't monitor

Tags: windows, hdmi

I have a soundbar that I connect to my PC. Windows thinks it's a monitor so it randomly opens up windows on that "screen", mouse can go there, etc. but because it doesn't exist, it's a pain.

Is there a way how to prevent Windows to think my soundbar is a monitor?
If I disable it as a screen in Windows display settings, sound doesn't work.
(I need to connect using HDMI because I need a quality output from it.)